# std::greater<int>()(100, 300), why is it working?

Tags: c++, functor

Per my understanding, Functor should be used as this

```
std::greater<int> g;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << g(10, 3) << std::endl;
```

or as parameter of a function.

```
find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>())
```

but what does this mean?

```
std::cout << std::greater<int>()(100, 300) << std::endl; // output: false
```

And when I use not_equal_to as below, it cannot pass compile:

```
int* pt = std::adjacent_find (numbers, numbers+5, std::not_equal_to<int>(1,1)) +1;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it working?

In the 1st code, you're calling `operator()` on the functor, and print out the result.

```
std::cout << std::greater<int>()(100, 300) << std::endl; // output: false  
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <- create a temporary object(functor)
                                ~~~~~~~~~~ <- call operator() on the temporary object
```

> Why isn't it working?

In the 2nd code, you're passing the functor to an algorithm, and the functor will be called inside the algorithm, by calling `operator()` on it.

```
int* pt = std::adjacent_find (numbers, numbers+5, std::not_equal_to<int>(1,1)) +1;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You're trying creating a temporary `std::not_equal_to` by a ctor taking 2 parameters. `std::not_equal_to` doesn't have that ctor, so just change it to use the default ctor, as you did for calling `std::find_if` with `std::greater`.

```
int* pt = std::adjacent_find (numbers, numbers+5, std::not_equal_to<int>()) +1;
```

Comment: your answer is confusing, after quote "why isn't it working" you explain why it works in the second case

Comment: @Slava After quote "why isn't it working" I'm trying to explain why it does *not* work...

Comment: @Slava Would you mind pointing out which part is confusing specifically?

Comment: There is a question in quote, then there is a sentence with the answer. Then there is a question in a quote again and sentence, that look like an answer again, but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, for a class X with a parameterless constructor, you can write `X()` as part of other expressions to create a (temporary stack-) object. Ie. following two codes are the same [if callFunc doesn't expect a changeable reference etc.]:

```
X x;  
callFunc(x);  

callFunc(X());
```

Now `std::greater<int>()(100, 300)` creates a object of `std::greater<int>` like above, and the executes the functor with parameters 100 and 300. It's just a combination of your first two code samples, a pair of parenthesis for object creation and one for calling it. In `std::not_equal_to<int>(1,1)`, you're missing a pair of parenthesis.

Comment: You mean use it this way?
`int* pt = std::adjacent_find (numbers, numbers+5, std::not_equal_to<int>()(1,1)) +1;`
still cannot pass compile. :(

Comment: @ponypaver No, he means: `std::adjacent_find (numbers, numbers+5, std::not_equal_to<int>())`

Comment: @fjardon This is the standard usage, I was wondering why greater can be used that way while not_equal_to cannot.

Comment: @ponypaver It *can* be used like this, if you want to directly invoke it: `bool b = std::not_equal_to<int>()(1,1);`. Note that passing it to an algorithm such as `std::adjacent_find` does *not* invoke it directly.